# Electromagnetic Inductance: Different voltmeter readings from different positions

Tags: electromagnetism, inductance

In the setup below, the voltmeter on the right would read differently than the voltmeter on the left even though they are both connected to point D and point A.

[image]

This picture is taken from Lecture 16 of MIT course 8.02.

It shows a circuit with a solenoid in the middle. The magnetic field of the solenoid is pointing out of the blackboard and at the moment it is turned on, there is an increase in magnetic field inducing a clockwise current in the wire.

The EMF is given to be 1V.

$ Given: V = 1  $
$ V=I(R_{1} + R_{2}) = I(100+900) = 1 $
$ \Rightarrow I = 0.001 $

By Ohm's Law,
$ Clockwise: V_{D} - V_{A} = IR_{2} = 0.9 $
$ Counter clockwise: V_{D} - V_{A} = -IR_{1} = -0.1 $

So the Voltmeter on the right will read 0.9 while the left will read -0.1.

[This is shown in an experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wmPiQm75arU#t=250) where two voltmeters connected to the same points A and D read different values.

How is this possible? How does the voltmeter "know" whether it is on the left or right? It seems entirely symmetrical. How would the experiment need to be setup? If I were to just take a voltmeter and connect it to point A and D, how would I know what it would read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It seems entirely symmetrical.

But it isn't symmetrical.

For the voltmeter on the right, the 'outer' loop that encloses the magnetic field consists of the voltmeter, leads, and a $100\Omega$ resistor

For the voltmeter on the left, the outer loop that encloses the magnetic field consists of the voltmeter, leads, and a $900\Omega$ resistor.

Moreover, the direction of the induced electric field is 'towards' the positive terminal of the voltmeter on the right but is 'away' from the positive terminal of the voltmeter on the left.

To gain further insight into this problem, consider a 3rd voltmeter connected across nodes A & D 'out' of the plane of the page such the leads are parallel to the magnetic field lines.

What voltage reading do you expect this voltmeter to give?

---

UPDATE:  here's a worked example of a similar problem, via [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=3a7z8TzxaDMC&pg=PT89#v=onepage&q&f=false), from "[Inductance: Loop and Partial](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470461888)" by Clayton R. Paul:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Interesting setup!

I assume that you understand that for a short time there is a (induced) current flowing in the loop with the two resistors. You can get the same current by imagining a battery that is in series with the loop (you can put it at A, for example).

With that battery in place, it is easy to see that the voltage across the 900r resistor will be different than the voltage across the 100r resistor. What is confusing you is the fact that the wire connecting the two, which you think of as "something that cannot have a voltage across it", does in fact (transiently) sustain a voltage - namely the EMF resulting from the rapid change in flux - but that is what is happening: the wire acts as a "battery", since there is a force on the electrons in the wire while the magnetic flux lines are driven across it.  Depending on the size of the wire (as a fraction of the total circumference of the loop), this voltage will be a greater or lesser percentage of the total voltage around the loop.

If you connected the two volt meters at exactly the same point in the circuit with leads that do not form a loop, they would in fact have to read the same voltage. But the loop of the volt meter leads forms part of the circuit too... And since these loops experience (different) flux changes you need to consider their impact as well.